# Convergence of series $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty}\sin(\frac{\pi\cdot n}{4})\cdot \sqrt[9]{\ln(\frac{n+12}{n+9})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

$$\sum_{n =1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\frac{\pi\cdot n}{4}\right)\cdot \sqrt[9]{\ln\left(\frac{n+12}{n+9}\right)}$$
How to find convergence of this series?
I researched the absolute convergence and get $$\exp^{\frac{1}{3\cdot (n+9)}}$$
Thanks a lot!

Comment: your series does converge

Comment: Please state what have you tried...

Comment: @AlexVong I researched the absolute convergence and get $\exp^{\frac{1}{3\cdot (n+9)}}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you explain why does it converge?

Comment: What do you mean by "I researched ..." and got that? Makes no sense. Surely you have some thoughts on this. Come on, what does the sequence $\sin(\pi n/4)$ look like?

Comment: @zhw. Criterio di Abel Dirichlet to research series

Comment: @zhw $|sin(\frac{\pi \cdot n}{4})| <= 1 + \sqrt{2}$

Comment: @zhw. It's right?

Comment: Well $|\sin x| \le 1$ for any $x,$ so I'm not sure where you're going.

Comment: @zhw. $${U}_n = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|sin(\frac{\pi \cdot n}{4})| <= 1 + \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Why do you have $U_n$ on the left side? And no, that series doesn't converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: The series does not converge absolutely. Proof idea: Sum over the indices $n=2,10,18,26,\dots.$ The series does converge conditionally. Proof idea: The partial sums of $\sum \sin(\pi n/4)$ are bounded and the terms $[\ln ((n+2)/(n+9))]^{1/9}$ decrease to $0.$

Comment: How to proof that series doesn't converge absolutely?

Comment: What happens when you sum over the indices I mentioned?

Comment: I've already solved this example, thanks